Remove a Duplicated inventory stock created from duplicate action by mistake on Odoo 17
While downloading the stocks of a warehouse from the inventory module, we have clicked on action/duplicate and all the stocks record has been duplicated without any trace of transaction created, how can we reverse the transaction of the duplication and get the balance back
we have been searching for any traceability of the transaction with no luck and we can't go for adjustments as the previous transaction didn't create any financial or transaction record on the inventory
